# twitter-bootstrap-rails application.css - invalide CSS

Tags: capistrano, twitter-bootstrap-rails

The line in application.css

*= require bootstrap_and_overrides

This works locally just fine. But
cap deploy
fails with:

Invalid CSS after "*": expected "{", was "= require boots..."

I moved the gem to outside the :development group but doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?
Thanks.